# Value range of unsigned qword (64-Bits) using less bits?

Tags: c++, assembly, binary, compression, number-theory

I'm looking for a way to represent the value range of: 
0 - 18446744073709551615 
using less than 8 bytes.

I have tried to think of some ways it can be done, but nothing works.
In theory, For example:
Using a single byte to represent the bit sequence of at least 2 bytes.
However, 2 bytes have a number of 65536 different combination of bits, while a single byte only gives us a value range of 0-255 (256 combinations).

The best way would probably be to change the meaning of the bits. That would be fine but there cant be any precision loss.

I'm starting to think its simply not possible, though i would like to get others opinions and theory's on the subject.

There's 2 rules:
#1 There cant be any precision loss (i.e, all numbers 0 - 18446744073709551615 must be representable).
#2 Conversion from standard 64-Bit form should never result in more than 7 bytes (56-Bits) being needed.

these rules make this particularly hard.

Comment: If all 2^64 numbers must all be representable, then you're done. 63 bits can only represent half of them. If you decompress all of the 63 bit compressed values, you will get, at most, half of the 64-bit values. Simple counting. 56 bits can only represent 1/256th of the numbers. You need 64 bits. Period.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> these rules make this particularly hard.

Yes, hard to the point of being provably impossible.

If you could losslessly compress 8 bytes to less-than-8 bytes for *every* possible 64b value, you could keep repeating the process until your 1TB file was about 7 bytes.

There are plenty of other information-theory arguments why this is impossible.  e.g. the pigeonhole principle: `n` bits only have 2^n unique bit patterns, so anything less than 64 bits can't have unique representations for every possible 64-bit value.

---

What you could usefully use is [Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) or similar:  A not-too-complex variable-length encoding scheme can save total bytes if some 64b values are more common than others.  **But for all 64b values to be representable with a variable-length coding scheme, the encoding for some values will take more than 8 bytes.**

More advanced entropy-coding methods exist, and are used in modern video codecs.  (e.g. x264's CABAC).

---

For more theory, Wikipedia's lossless compression articls has a [Limitations section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression#Limitations).

See also:

- [cstheory.SE: Which is the limit of lossless compression data? (if there exists such a limit)](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7027/which-is-the-limit-of-lossless-compression-data-if-there-exists-such-a-limit)
- [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity)